# Elasticsearch - how to search exact string match with special charater (-) in the json document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

i have been using ES 5.x version and this is my sample data set json.

```
{"id":"1"}
{.... "company" : "HCL-US",....}
{"id":"2"}
{.... "company" : "HCL",....}
{"id":"3"}
{.... "company" : "HCL-IND",....}
{"id":"4"}
{.... "company" : "HCL-AUS",....}
```

How can i search and get who is belonging to "HCL-US". i tried using this query "_search?q=company:"HCL-US"" , it is returning HCL * result. How can i match exact string with special string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Term Query` that matches exact term. Assuming `company` is a `text` field, you will get a `keyword` version of the same , following query should do the needful

```
{

 "query": {
  "term": {
    "company.keyword": {
    "value": "HCL-US"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1/ You can specify a [whitespace analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) in the mapping for the field `company`. This analyzer will split the query only on whitespace while the standard will split on non-alphanumeric characters.

The standard analyzer is the one used when no analyzer is defined.

2/ Or your can query on `company.keyword` which is a field automatically created for text field since 5.X . This keyword is not analyzed and you can safely use a term query on it to do exact matching.